# Success event is never triggered in my javascript for polling event

Tags: javascript

Very new to programming.
I am trying to develop a web application using django and celery. I want to display a loader till some background celery, task is executing and then display the data fetched by celery worker.
Till now, my state is this
My *loader.js* script is:

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function poll1() {
 setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8000/celery-progress/task_progress/12/",
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      type: "GET",
      success: function(myFunction) }}

(function poll(){       
      $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:8000/celery-progress/task_progress/12/",type: "GET", success: function showPage1() {
      document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
      }, dataType: "json"});      
})();

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

When the html body load, I have tried calling both *poll1* and *poll*. **But my loader keeps on rotating indefinitely.**
The data returned by the polling url "http://localhost:8000/celery-progress/task_progress/12/" is a json

> "{"complete": true, "success": true, "progress": {"current": 100,
>   "total": 100, "percent": 100}}"

Any help would be great!

Comment: 1. Your brackets don't add up. 2. What do you think `success: function(myFunction)` does?

Comment: I copied the poll1 and poll functions from internet. For the first one the brackets don't add up. I basically want the polling function to poll the url every second and when the  returned json has success event set to true, it should call the showPage function.

Comment: The success member expects a function. `function(myFunction)` is nothing more than a syntax error. You can simply say `success: myFunction` to pass a reference to the `myFunction` function to it. You do need to fix all the brackets in order for it to work. A decent IDE should highlight for you which opening bracket belongs to which closing bracket. Make sure they all add up.

Comment: Two more clarifications :    1) When does the success event gets triggered? Does it depend on the json returned by my polling URL. How does it know that there is success now.    2) poll1 has correct syntax, so shouldn't the poll1 function work fine on success?

Comment: The success get's triggered after the browser receives a successful response. Successful in this sense means [HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) in the 200~299 range. When you get a status in the range of 400~499 or 500~599, it will not execute. (I'm unsure about 100~199 and 300~399.)

Comment: oh okay. Understood :) . The second clarification still remains though. ..... Also it would really help if you could give me a syntactically correct function to implement the above functionality as I am new to ajax and don't have the patience to learn it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
you must assign a function to the success property, it means that you're not supposed to write it like you did ( that was like you were defining a new function with another function as it's argument )
try this:

```
function poll1() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/celery-progress/task_progress/12/",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    type: "GET",
    success: myFunction
  })
}
```

you did one other job that i could not understand well, I mean using setTimeout in poll1 function.
 so I removed it.
now, with the code above, 3 seconds after your AJAX success, showPage function will be invoked, if you don't want to wait for 3 seconds you can simply assign showPage directly to success property.

Comment: Thanks @Kavian :) . Really helpful. Need some clarifications. **1) How often the polling url will be invoked to check for success( i 1times/sec or 1times/3secs). 2) Can you please elaborate when you say 'assign showPage directly to success property'. How can i do that ? **        Regarding what you . asked, i just copied this function from internet and tried it. Didn't know that setTimeout was not req :p .

Comment: @codeaprendiz 1) I think you've misunderstood how AJAX method works here, this is an event listener that does what you want "Just once" just when the request succeed, you don't need to check if it is done(search about event listeners), 2) just do this: success: showPage, (if you found my answer helpful, please don't forget to mark it as the best answer) good luck

Comment: 1) For the event listener to listen to success event, it has to poll the url. The url will return 200(success) or 400(failure) depending on status of task. So HOW OFTEN IT POLLS FOR THE SAME TO GET STATUS??? 2) oh okay. Definitely your ans is helpful:). I have voted it already but my votes are bot counted yet since I am a new bie.

Comment: @codeaprendiz every time you call function poll1 it, in your words, it checks once, but if you want to send request every x seconds and do the same repeatedly you should use setInterval

Comment: So this isn’t really a nice approach to check the status of task as it defeats the purpose of polling. It would be really nice if you could give an example of setInterval which achieves this by polling every second with initial delay of fixed second (like 5). :)